# Can't figure out the reason of Infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I programmed the Hangman game using python. I'm getting an Infinite loop after no more chances remaining.

```
import random
import time
import sys

# Returns a word
def get_word(): 
    words = ["apple", "sandwitch", "chance", "winner", "chicken", "dinner"]
    return random.choice(words)

# Checks whether the character is in the word or not    
def check_character(character, word, newWord):
    word = list(word)
    temp = list(newWord)
    flag = False
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == character:
            temp[i] = character
            flag = True
        elif str(word[i]).isalpha() == True:
            pass
        else:
            temp[i] = '*'
    newWord = ''.join(temp)
    return [newWord, flag]      # flag is True if character was in word else False  


def play(name):
    chances = 3
    points = 0
    loop = True
    print("Welcome {} you have {} chances and your points are {}. ".format(name, chances, points))

    while loop:
        # This loop is getting executed infinitly after no more chances available
        word = get_word()
        print("Word is : {}".format(len(word)* '*'))
        newWord = len(word) * '*'

        while chances != 0:
            if '*' in newWord:
                character = input("Enter a character: ")
                temp = check_character(character, word, newWord)
                newWord, flag = temp[0], temp[1]
                if chances == 0:
                    print("Guess was wrong. No remaining chances .")
                    print("Your score was: {}".format(points))
                    sys.exit(0) # sys.exit() also not working after all the chances are gone
                elif flag == False and chances != 0:
                    chances = chances - 1
                    print("Guess was wrong. Chances remaining are {}".format(chances))
                else:
                    print("Word is : {}".format(newWord))
            else:
                print("Hurray!!! you have guessed the word correctly.")
                points = points + 1
                print("Your points: {}".format(points))
                print("Your remaining chances: {} ".format(chances))
                loop = input("Would you like to continue(True/False only):")
                break


print("Welcome to the Hangman Game!!!! ")
time.sleep(1)
print("Loading.", end= "")
time.sleep(1)
print(".", end= "")
time.sleep(1)
print(".", end= "")
time.sleep(1)
print(".")

name = input("Enter your Name: ")
play(name)
```

The outer while loop is executed and remaining working is proper. When there are no more chances the outer while still execute irrespective of the loop value.

**After removing all the errors**
There were two errors the loop was typecasted to string and the outer while loop was not having chances = 3. After a few tweaks it is working file the correct code is below and also the GitHub code has been updated as well.

```
import random
import time
import sys

def get_word():
    words = ["apple", "sandwitch", "chance", "winner", "chicken", "dinner"]
    return random.choice(words)

def check_character(character, word, newWord):
    word = list(word)
    temp = list(newWord)
    flag = False
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == character:
            temp[i] = character
            flag = True
        elif str(word[i]).isalpha() == True:
            pass
        else:
            temp[i] = '*'
    newWord = ''.join(temp)
    return [newWord, flag]        


def play(name):
    chances = 3
    points = 0
    loop = True
    print("Welcome {} you have {} chances and your points are {}. ".format(name, chances, points))

    while loop:
        chances = 3
        word = get_word()
        print("Word is : {}".format(len(word)* '*'))
        newWord = len(word) * '*'

        while chances != 0:
            if '*' in newWord:
                character = input("Enter a character: ")
                temp = check_character(character, word, newWord)
                newWord, flag = temp[0], temp[1]
                if flag == False and chances == 1:
                    print("Guess was wrong. No remaining chances .")
                    print("Your score was: {}".format(points))
                    sys.exit(0)
                elif flag == False and chances > 0:
                    chances = chances - 1
                    print("Guess was wrong. Chances remaining are {}".format(chances))
                else:
                    print("Word is : {}".format(newWord))
            else:
                print("Hurray!!! you have guessed the word correctly.")
                points = points + 1
                print("Your points: {}".format(points))
                print("Your remaining chances: {} ".format(chances))
                answer = input("Do you wish to continue ? (Y/N)").upper() 
                if answer == "N":
                    loop = False
                break    

print("Welcome to the Hangman Game!!!! ")
time.sleep(1)
print("Loading.", end= "")
time.sleep(1)
print(".", end= "")
time.sleep(1)
print(".", end= "")
time.sleep(1)
print(".")

name = input("Enter your Name: ")
play(name)
```

I have also created a GitHub repository of this program [click here](https://github.com/abhi7585/Hangman-using-python).

Comment: `loop` is a string and a non-empty string is always true-ish.

Comment: It is not idiomatic to use a loop's condition as the user input directly. You would want to do some input validation and `break` accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two logical mistakes with your loops.

The first mistake is that you asked the user to enter True or False in this line:

```py
loop = input("Would you like to continue(True/False only):")
```

But this will be entered as a string, not a Boolean, so the outer loop will continue forever regardless of what the user enters. You need to convert it to a Boolean e.g. using

```py
loop = input("Would you like to continue (True/False only):")
loop = loop.lower() == 'true' # do case-insensitive comparison to get a Boolean
```

The second mistake is that if the user does want to play again, you need to reset `chances`, otherwise it will still be zero, and the user will never get the opportunity to make a guess on the next game. So you should move `chances = 3` to the start of the first loop, instead of before it.

Comment: I didn't add chances = 3 again because the user gets only 3 chances and the user has to solve as many words using those chances. I get your point it would be more appropriate.

Comment: But if you don't reset `chances = 3` then its meaningless to restart the outer loop after the user has run out of chances. You'll get an infinite loop because the program chooses a new word, but the user has no more chances, so they lose immediately and the program chooses another new word, and so on. If you don't want the chances to be reset to 3 for the next game, then you need to change the logic so that the outer loop also stops when there are no chances left.

Answer (score 2):

```py
loop = input("Would you like to continue(True/False only):")
```

This line is your culprit you are setting loop to the string "True" or "False" not a boolean value

A Simple fix would be something like :

```py
loop = (input("Would you like to continue(True/False only):") == "True")
```

Which compares the input to a string value and returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

Your main loop using the condition `while loop`. However, in your code:

- You never `break` that loop
- You change the loop value using `loop = input("Would you like to continue(True/False only):")`

The input will return a string, and in you `while` assertion:

- If the string is "", then it is equivalent to `False`
- Otherwise, if the string is anything else, it is equivalent to `True`

Therefore, if your user inputs ANYTHING, it will be treated as "loop is still true".

To fix your problem, you must handle the user input

```py
answer = input("Do you wish to continue ? (Y/N)").upper() ?
if answer == "N":
    loop = False
```